# JPQL query by foreign key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

There are two tables PersonEntity and cityentity. PersonEntity in the database is linked to cityentity by the external key fk_cityid. I need to select all the records (names) of the PersonEntity table with the given CityId. Join is used everywhere for this, but in this case I don't need data from the cityentity table, only the name field of the PersonEntity table. Here is a description of the classes:

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private CityEntity cityId;
}
@Entity
public class CityEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Here is the HQL query:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
  @Query("select p.name FROM PersonEntity p where (p.name = :name or :name is null) " +
        "and (p.cityId = :cityId or :cityId is null)")
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndCity (
        @Param("name") String name,
        @Param("cityId") CityEntity cityId);
}
```

tried by id:

```
@Query("select p.name FROM PersonEntity p where (p.name = :name or :name is null) " +
        "and (p.cityId.id = :cityId or :cityId is null)")
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndCity (
        @Param("name") String name,
        @Param("cityId") Long cityId);
```

In both cases, the error is: "the data type could not be determined".

options for calling the function:

```
servisPerson.findByNameAndCity (null, cityId);
```

or

```
servisPerson.findByNameAndCity (name, null);
```

In fact, there are more than two parameters. I only show two for simplification.

```
servisPerson.findByNameAndCity (name, age, ..., cityId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person entity should look something like this

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity {
     private Long id;
     private String name;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
     private CityEntity city;
}
```

Than you can write your query like this

```
List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndCityOrNameIsNullOrCityIsNull(String name, CityEntity city);
```

Spring Data JPA is so smart to generate the query for you under the hood.

BTW, you attempted to write [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence_Query_Language), not [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

EDIT (reaction on comment about long method names):

I would suggest to avoid creating JPQL query, because is is more error prone. If you don't like lengthy method name, you can wrap it into shorter default method within repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonEntityRepository extends  JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
     List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndCityOrNameIsNullOrCityIsNull(String name, CityEntity city);
     
     default List<PersonEntity> shortName(String name, CityEntity city) {
         return findByNameAndCityOrNameIsNullOrCityIsNull(name, city);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. But the fact is that any of the fields can be = null. And then such a request causes an error. To do this, I added "or: name is zero" to HQL". How to write this in Spring Data JPA I do not know. findByNameOrIsNullAndCityOrIsNull ??? Not sure if this is correct

Comment: right sorry, I missed piece about nulls. Initially focused only on link issue in PersonEntity. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. But how to do it on HQL? Because on JPQL the function name will be too big. findByNameAndCityAndAggAnd.....OrNameIsNullOrCityIsNullOrAggIsNullOr.....

Comment: @Alex, Edited my answer to reflect also this comment.

Comment: It doesn't work like this. Function findByNameAndCityOrNameIsNullOrCityIsNull always returns an empty list. findByNameAndCityOrNameIsNullOrCityIsNull ("name", "city") - this is how it works. And so  findByNameAndCityOrNameIsNullOrCityIsNull ("name", null) returns an empty list